# 母になる vs. お母さんになる

Tags: word-choice

There is an example sentence:

> お母さんになって初めて、母・お母さんの辛さが分かる。

I was told that the first お母さん couldn’t be replaced with 母, because it must refer to someone else's mother (one cannot be one's own mother), but that the second can be either 母(the speaker's own mother) or お母さん(someone else's mother).

However, I'm not quite convinced.

I feel that 母 not only can refer to the speaker's own mother, but can also refer to herself as a mother or maybe mothers in general. Is it possible to say 母になって初めて?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depends on the context. If you are saying this to a specific pregnant person in front of you, it's usually better to say お母さん because it sounds polite yet friendly.

However, if this sentence is presented without any further context, it looks like a description of mothers in general, and keigo is not particularly relevant. You can safely use both 母 or お母さん without being rude to someone. Simply, 母 sounds more formal or stiff, while お母さん sounds more casual. It's better to use the same word throughout the sentence to avoid confusion.

- お母さんになって初めて、お母さんの辛さが分かる。
- 母になって初めて、母の辛さが分かる。

Comment: What if someone wants to mean that “Only after I/you become a mother myself/yourself, will I/you understand my/your own mother’s bitterness”. (Or in past tense: ... became..., did ...)

Comment: @Mathis It depends on whether the mother is "I" or "you", and it also depends on how much keigo you have to use. お母さん should be safe in most situations, though.

Comment: Yeah, there are many scenarios, one that I feel confusing is: If the first “mother” refers to the speaker herself and the second “mother” refers to her mother, and she says this to her mother. Is it better for her to refer to herself as お母さん or 母? And how about referring to her own mother? Since two “mother”s refer to two different specific persons, I guess it is better to use different forms of address.

Comment: @Mathis In that situation keigo is not relevant (you don't usually use keigo to your family), so 母 is not an option. The second "mother" is essentially "you", and it depends on how you call your mother (which [differs from family to family](https://www.danlan.jp/_ct/17229622)).